# Why doesn't SASM's debugger show the value of a "result" variable updating after a store?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-64, debug-symbols, sasm

I'm trying to run a simple code in assembly - I want to save an address to memory.

I'm moving the address into a register and then moving it into the memory, but for some reason the memory isn't updated.

```
.data 
str1: .asciz "atm course number is 234118"
str2: .asciz "234118"
result: .space 8

.text
.global main
main:
    xorq  %rax, %rax
    xorq %rbx, %rbx
    leaq str1, %rax
    mov %rax, result(,%rbx,1)
    ret
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You don't need an index register; it would be more efficient to use `mov %rax, result(%rip)` (and not bother zeroing RBX) or `mov %rax, result(%rbx,,)` if you did want to use a byte offset.  The latter only works in a non-PIE executable, but since your current code linked and ran we know that's what you have.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank for your answer but none of these worked... im still getting the same result - cant update thi place in memory...

Comment: I didn't say that was the problem, sorry.  Just that those are more efficient ways to do exactly the same thing.  I was expecting to write another comment right away for some simple problem instead of leaving you hanging, but it was more tricky than I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your debugger is looking at the wrong instance of `result`.  Your code was always fine** (although inefficient; use `mov %rax, result(%rip)` and don't zero an index, or use `mov %rax, result(%rbx,,)` to use the byte offset as a "base", not "index", which is more efficient).

glibc contains several `result` symbols, and in GDB `info var result` shows:

```
All variables matching regular expression "result":

Non-debugging symbols:
0x000000000040404b  result         # in your executable, at a normal static address
0x00007ffff7f54f20  result_type
0x00007ffff7f821b8  cached_result
0x00007ffff7f846a0  result         # in glibc, at a high address
0x00007ffff7f85260  result         #  where the dynamic linker puts shared libs
0x00007ffff7f85660  result
0x00007ffff7f86ab8  result
0x00007ffff7f86f48  result
```

**When I do `p /x &result` to see what address the debugger resolved that symbol to, I get one of the glibc instances, *not* the instance in your `.data` section.**   Specifically, I get `0x7ffff7f85660` as the address, with the content = 0.

When I print the *value* with a cast to `p /x (unsigned long)result`, or dump the memory with GDB's `x` command, I find a `0` there after the store.

```
(gdb) x /xg &result
0x7ffff7f85660 <result>:        0x0000000000000000
```

It looks like your system picked a different instance, one that contained a pointer to a libc address or something.  I can't copy-paste from your image.  These other `result` variables are probably `static int result` or whatever inside various `.c` files in glibc.  (And BTW, that looks like a sign of poor coding style; usually you want to return a value instead of set a global or static.  But glibc is old and/or maybe there's some justification for some of those.)

Your `result:` is the asm a compiler would make for `static void* result` if it didn't get optimized away.  Except it would put it in `.bss` instead of `.data` because it's zero-initialized.

---

**You're using SASM.  I used GDB to get more details on exactly what's going on.**  Looking at the address of `result` in SASM's debug pane might have helped.  But now that we've identified the problem using GDB, we can change your source to fix it for SASM.

---

**You can use `.globl result` to make it an externally-visible symbol so it "wins" when the debugger is looking for symbols.**

I added that and compiled again with `gcc -g -no-pie store.s`.  It works as expected now, with `p /x (unsigned long)result` giving `0x404028`

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer. that helped me a lot!

Comment: @E.Ginzburg: You can click the "accept" checkmark under the vote arrows if this fully answers your question.